# SQL: Joining 3 tables with sums, filtering on non-aggregated columns

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have the following tables:

```
    Plant:
ID      Name
1       Plant1
2       Plant2
......

   Rejects:
PlantID Quantity  Date
1       20        01/02/2012
1       3         02/02/2012
2       30        03/02/2012
.....

  Parts
PlantID Quantity  Date
1       300       01/02/2012
2       500       01/02/2012
1       600       02/02/2012
.......
```

I'm trying to join the three so that I have a sum of parts and rejects per plant between two dates:

```
Plant   Parts   Rejects
Plant1       900     23
Plant2       500     30
.....
```

I've tried joins, which just multiplies the sums and I've tried subqueries that won't let me use a date filter because it's not used in the group by clause.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime
select @startDate = '1/1/2012', @endDate = '2/1/2012'

select
    p.Name as Plant,

    (select sum(Quantity) 
     from Parts 
     where PlantID = p.ID and date between @startDate and @endDate) as Parts,

    (select sum(Quantity) 
     from Rejects 
     where PlantID = p.ID and date between @startDate and @endDate) as Rejects
from
    Plant p
where
    p.endDate is null
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this works perfectly.  Now that I'm bringing back null results, I need to be able to filter by plant with an enddate flag that isn't set.  Is that possible with this query?

Comment: @user1228983 Where is the `endDate` flag?  Is that another column in the `plant` table?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I left out what I thought was irrelevant to keep the post tidy!

Comment: @user1228983 Please see my edit... is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Of course, the answer was obvious.  I'd been staring at code for far too long and was using "is not null", wondering why all my results were empty!  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
select p.Name as Plant,
       SUM(t.Quantity) as Parts,
       SUM(r.Quantity) as Rejects
from Plant p
inner join Rejects r on p.ID = r.PlantID
inner join Parts t on p.ID = PlantID
group by p.Name
```

You make the `INNER JOIN` between all tables using `ID`. Afterwards you just need the `SUM` of the `Quantities` in `Parts` and `Rejects`. For that you need to use the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the response, but that doesn't allow me to filter by date.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (using oracle):

```
SELECT NVL(p.plantid, r.plantid), NVL(parts,0), NVL(rejects,0)
FROM 
    (SELECT plantid, sum(quantity) as parts
    FROM parts
    WHERE date BETWEEN a AND b) p
        FULL JOIN
    (SELECT plantid, sum(quantity) as rejects
    FROM rejects
    WHERE date BETWEEN a and b) r
       ON p.plantid = r.plantid
```

Note that this will not get plants with no rejects or parts.